# 413 Request Entity Too Large - Entidad de solicitud demasiada larga

Tags: php, laravel

Bueno todo el dia de hoy estuve batallando con el problema del titulo 413 too large, lo que intente fue cambiarle los datos en el php ini y puse por ejemplo :

```
upload_max_filesize=200M
max_file_uploads=20
post_max_size=200M
```

tambien agregue lo siguiente al nginx:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera :

```
 location /prueba/ {
         alias /var/www/html/prueba/api/public/;
         index index.php;
         try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelprueba;

         location ~ \.php {
                  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                  proxy_connect_timeout  3600;
                  proxy_send_timeout    3600;
                  proxy_read_timeout    3600;
                  send_timeout      3600;
                  fastcgi_read_timeout 3500;
                  client_max_body_size 3600M;  
         }

   }
```

tire tambien comandos como:

```
sudo service php-fpm reload
sudo service nginx restart
```

Pero sigo sin encontrar la solucion el archivo que intento subir pesa 1.3 mb nada mas no es tan pesado.

Comment: probaste cambiar el php.ini?

Comment: si es lo que puse en la descripcion.

Comment: que dice tu  phpinfo();  ?

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia 3 archivos en el que podia agregar el client max tuve que agregarselo a la siguiente ruta etc/nginx/nginx.conf y agregarle el `client_max_body_size 3600M;` y funciono al darle  `sudo service nginx restart`